# Center Item in Menu bar

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react and I'm working with `<Menu>` to create a menu bar. The problem is that I'm trying to centre an item in the top bar. Right now I have 2 items on the left, an item on the right and an item that is centered between the latest left item and right item.
[Here is a sandbox of what I'm talking about.](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-elbakyan-xqx1v)

What I really want is the item in the centre to be in the middle of the screen (or at the centre of the top bar) regardless of how many items are on the left and on the right (unless obviously there are too many items on the left or right but for this case I only want two items on the left and one on the right). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

> **OLD**
>   [image]
>
> **NEW**
>   [image]

Here for **Center Item Style**

```
style={{
   position: "fixed",
   left: "50%",
   transform: "translate(-50%, 0)"
}}
```

Main factor is

- `position: "fixed"` or `"absolute"` that make item not care another items position
- `left: "50%"` will make item middle of the screen **BUT** start position of item will be at screen middle
- `tranfrom: "translate(-50%,0)"` will pull back position of own 50% width and 0 height

Comment: This is working pretty well but the only problem is when I change the width of the browser, the middle item will overlap with the left items.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to place all the right nav items in one div, the left nav items in one div and the center item you can place in a div or leave as is. Than you can tinker with how you want to space out the three divs in your header, ie space-between or space-around.

Something like this maybe?
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-satoshi-estgd?fontsize=14